# EXC_BAD_ACCEss code=1error when populating UILabel text property

Tags: ios, exc-bad-access

I'm setting the text for a label, but it sometimes crashes with,

```
EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, adress=xxxxxxxxx)
```

and when it doesnt crash the labels shows this

`"Friday 10:00 AM - 10:50 AM - (action=longDelayRecognizer:, target=<UITextInteractionAssistant 0x1701d4280>)""`

or this

```
- -2.312090474116815e+16"
```

this is how im populating the view

```
  guard let breakoutTime = self.classSelected?.breakout?.breakoutShortFormatTimes(),
        let breakoutDay = self.classSelected?.breakout?.getBreakoutDay()
        else {
            return
    }
    self.title = String(format:"%@ %@ - %@", breakoutDay, breakoutTime)
```

so im not sure what to make of this. Any help is appreciatted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line

```
self.title = String(format:"%@ %@ - %@", breakoutDay, breakoutTime)
```

contains **three** placeholders `%@ %@ - %@` but only **two** arguments `breakoutDay, breakoutTime`.

The number of placeholders must match the number of arguments.

Comment: Well... I feel so freaking dumb now... Thank you though!